# How to center a Material UI FAB button and having it stay centered with window re-sizing?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

As the title states, I would like for a MaterialUI FAB button to be centered and stay centered with resizing. The current placement is shown in the screenshot below (off-center) and it does not re-size with window change.

Here is the current FAB button component. It is a child component and I have shown the parent below as well.

**I cannot get "justifyContent: "center"" to work as it normally does, as a note.**

Any help on centering this and allowing it to scale with window size is welcome! thanks!

**FAB button child component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import NavigationIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Navigation';
import { navigate } from "@reach/router";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
        position: 'fixed',
        bottom: "5vh",
        right: "50vw",
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        width: "20vw"
    },
  },
  fab:{
    // fontSize: "35px"
  },
  extendedIcon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    // fontSize: "35px"
  },
}));

export default function AddListingIcon() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Fab color="green" aria-label="add" size="large" variant="extended" className={classes.fab} >
        <NavigationIcon onClick={() => {
              navigate("/ChooseACategory")}} className={classes.extendedIcon}/>
              Get Started!
      </Fab>
    </div>
  )
        }
```

**Parent component which contains the FAB button child component**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactNavbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Intro from "../components/Intro";
import GetStartedIcon from "../components/GetStartedIcon"

export default function GetStarted({ setSignedIn }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactNavbar setSignedIn={setSignedIn} />
      <Intro />
      <GetStartedIcon/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as your wrote it (obviously). The right side of your button is centered as it should be.

You rather need to wrap the Button in a **Flexbox**. You can use the **MUI Grid** for that with a `width:'100%'`, `position:fixed` and the prop `justify="center"`.

Here is a jsfiddle with plain css
https://jsfiddle.net/rq6kvw12/